# jQuery simple price * qty total on multiple items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for an automatic `total` calculation for multiple instances of `item` on load. I tried finding the `price` and `qty` for each `item` but the total is not calculating.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var total = qty * price;
    $('.total').val(total);
  });
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">50</div>
  <div class="price">10</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">20</div>
  <div class="price">50</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">19</div>
  <div class="price">40</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `<div>` elements do not have a `.val()`, only input-like elements have values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use text and number function to calculate:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('.qty').text();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').text();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    $(this).find('.total').text(total);
  });
});
```

Comment: $('.total').val(total); will not work, you have write as $('.total').text(total);

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your final .total also need the `$(this).find()` or it will match on all of them

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example using [jQuery#text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and converting to numeric values using [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())

Code:

```js
$('.item').each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $this.find('.total').text(
    +$this.find('.qty').text() * +$this.find('.price').text()
  );
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">50</div>
  <div class="price">10</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">20</div>
  <div class="price">50</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">19</div>
  <div class="price">40</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think find may cause performance hit.
>
> Use normal class selector.

I found this [article](https://jsperf.com/selector-vs-find-again) for the same

```js
// Find may cause performace overhead. 
$('.item').each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $('.total',$this).text(
    +$('.qty',$this).text() * +$('.price',$this).text()
  );
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">50</div>
  <div class="price">10</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">20</div>
  <div class="price">50</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="qty">19</div>
  <div class="price">40</div>
  <div class="total">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is parse the variable into it's type i.e. into Numbers or Int or Float

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var qty = $(this).find('.qty').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').val();
    var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);
    $('.total').val(total);
  });
});
```

You can replace `parseFloat` into `Number` too. Also if you don't need decimal values use `parseInt`